# Loading image not working it before the ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm done a sync AJAX request and I would like to show a image at before the AJAX call.

the javascript with the request

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$('#loading').modal('show');
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
var url1 = "/upload";
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
    success: function(data) {
        var msg = data.msg;
        var obj = data.obj;
        if (data.success == true) {
            $('input').val('');
            $('#loading').modal('hide');
            //logic here
        } else {
            //logic here
        }
    }
});

function beforeSendHandler(xhr) {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
}
```

this works in firefox but doesn't in chrome, i found different solutions in `stackoverflow`, and i tried. But i didn't get exact solution.

My chrome version :62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Which part exactly doesn't work? Did you observe the JS console for any error?

Comment: @31piy: when i am uploading file on that time it calls ajax code. When i stop the server it is showing. On that time in concole `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` getting.

Comment: Are you sure `#loading` DOM element exists before this code is executed?

Comment: @Vivek Athalye: Yeah. I commented total `ajax` call code. it is showing image. When i call ajax request on that time only it not showing.

Comment: function(){
            //submit button id
                  $('#loading').html('Processing...');
            } in the beforeSendHandler

Comment: @jeevanswamy21: not working

Comment: beforeSendHandler insted of this one call this function(){  $('#loading').html('Processing...'); } is their any print in console are xhr debug mode

Comment: There's no need for `async: false` here. You're using the "success" callback as intended. This feature just locks the browser's UI during the request, making it seem to the user like it's crashed, especially if the request takes longer than expected. It's deprecated as well, so won't work in future anyway. You can delete that line.

Comment: @ADyson: Thank you. It is working fine. I have small doubt there is any problem we will get in feature in different browsers?

Comment: @Durga no, all browsers support async ajax. Some have deprecated the synchronous calls. I didn't say it wouldn't work, I said it provides a bad user experience and also it'll stop working _in future_ (because it's deprecated).